# How can I mirror an ubuntu repository in freebsd?

Tags: ubuntu, repository, archive, freebsd

Is there a way to properly mirror an Ubuntu repository from FreeBSD?

The Debian website refers to a tool called `ftpsync` which I can install in FreeBSD with `pkg install ftpsync` but I am unable to actually execute the command (I can't find it) or find its manual entry (although I managed to get a link to documentation: [FtpSync manual in linuxfrance.org](http://www.linux-france.org/prj/ftpsync/README).

Assuming Debian and Ubuntu repositories work in the same way, the solution should allow me to perform a 2-stage sync and must not ignore pushes when running, as described here: [Setting up a Debian archive mirror](https://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror#how)

The reason I have to use ftpsync instead of rsync is to perform a partial mirroring: I want to download packages for the AMD64 and i386 versions only.

In Ubuntu I use `apt-mirror`, but there is not an equivalent program/script in FreeBSD that I could find.

Comment: Judging from Makefile, this `ftpsync` is installed as `ftpsync.pl`. Try that.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a tray